# Avoid paging when Allocating big blocks of memory in C?

Tags: c, memory, paging

I am writing an N-body simulation in C using the Barnes-Hut algorithm which requires using big blocks of memory. I am going for speed and efficiency. Is there any way to guarantee that these blocks of memory will stay in RAM and not get paged to the hard drive?

Edit: I would like to allocate as many as 2GB, however it is conceivable that I may end up running some simulations with much more memory.

Edit: Solution should support Windows7 (maybe Windows8 when it comes out?) and Ubuntu

Comment: If your entire application fits in the physical memory and you don't have other processes running, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.

Comment: This sounds like "OS land" stuff; that is, the OS will do what it wants :) Perhaps include the target OS as an aspect of the question as there may be tricks to tell it to "favor" certain programs in resource allocation ..

Comment: There is nothing in the C language standard that can give such a guarantee.

Comment: Darn... I have two operating systems I want to support, I'll put them in the question.

Comment: I'm not expecting pure C, but I was hoping that there might be conventions that operating systems follow that might lend themselves to some non-standard code or libraries, I'm just grasping for something that might work.

Comment: This is way outside conventions that both Windows 7 and Ubuntu follow, as far as code or libraries. You need to a) buy enough memory for your application and b) give your application high priority so other applications don't grab its pages, if there are such applications. In other words ... what Kerrek said.

Comment: Have you profiled your application and established beyond reasonable doubt that being paged out is a significant problem?

Comment: I'm in the middle of programming it and there isn't a working version yet. I have tried this before and I was fairly sure that paging was a contributing factor to my program's slowness (that and bad programming). So, in trying again, I am using an OS with a little less overhead (Ubuntu) and my approach will be radically different, but paging seems like such an insidious performance leech; I would want to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are operating system primitives that do what you want: [`mlock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) on Unix (of which Ubuntu is but one example¹), and [`VirtualLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895.aspx) on Windows.  (Ignore the quibbling in the comments over the exact semantics of VirtualLock; they're irrelevant for your use case.)

The Unix primitive requires `root` privilege in the calling process (some systems permit locking down a *small* amount of memory without privilege, but you want far more than that).  The Windows primitive appears not to require special privileges.

¹ "Linux is not UNIX" objection noted and ignored with prejudice.

Comment: Yes! I knew this would be possible. I will work on implementing these, thank you so much!

Comment: Although I may not support Windows now for convenience (I really don't like the Windows API).

Answer (score 1):

For Linux: mlock(2) will do the job.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mlock.2.html

But beware that the amount of user mlockable memory is normally limited on standard systems `ulimit -l`.

The Windows version is VirtualLock. I do not know if there is a limit and how it can be queried.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx